# error of accessing IBM netezza SQL server from pypyodbc on win7

Tags: python, sql, database, pydev, pypyodbc

I need to access IBM netezza SQL database from python on win 7.
I have installed Eclipse and python 3.2, pydev, and pypyodbc (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypyodbc/1.3.3). 
It worked well for MS SQL server.

But, it got error for IBM netezza.

```
   import pypyodbc

   conn = pypyodbc.connect("DRIVER={NetezzaSQL};SERVER={my_server_name};DATABASE={my_database};UID=a_user;PWD=apwd")

   pypyodbc.DatabaseError: ('08001', '[08001] Client unable to establish connection')
```

I can access the database from IBM Aginity workbench without any problems on the same desktop and laptop.

Any help would be appreciated.

thanks !

Comment: A few questions, do you have the netezza odbc drivers installed?  (I think you must if you have Aginity working...)  Are they both 64/32 bit?  Also, try changing `UID` to `username` and `PWD` to `password`.  Also, did you have any luck getting it to work with pyodbc?